# Install Chrome Driver

Tags: google-chrome, watir, watir-webdriver

1. I've downloaded the chrome driver for Win 7 32-bit OS. On executing .exe file, a command prompt opens with the message *Started ChromeDriver port=9515* I tried running this code, but chrome doesn't open...

   ```
   require "rubygems"
   require "watir-webdriver"
   #browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox) Firefox however opens
   #browser = Watir::Browser.new(:internet_explorer) IE too opens
   browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
   browser.goto "http://google.com"
   ```

I've only these two files **bridge.rb** and **service.rb** in the following folder: *C:\Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\selenium-webdriver-0.2.0\lib\selenium\webdriver\chrome*
Also, I've got the latest chrome installed 12.0.742.53

Question 2: This code doesn't maximize the browser in webdriver `browser.maximize`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to run the server manually. If chromedriver.exe is on your PATH, WebDriver will manage the server process for you.

If you *want* to manage the server yourself, you can still do that, but you'll need to create a :remote driver instead of :chrome:

```
Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => "http://localhost:9515")
```

If you're still having trouble, running your script with `$DEBUG = true` (or passing `-d` to 
Ruby on the command line) will give additional debug output.

You'll find more info about how the Chrome driver works [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver).

Comment: Looks like SO does not think ) is part of the link, so the link is broken, maybe it will work in my comment:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28variable%29

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. I figured out the issue which was the anti-virus which was blocking the chrome driver to run as it automatically starts app. So if you put the exception to the antivirus such that it doesn't block chrome driver, it should work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying..I do not have any anti-virus. Y would it block chrome driver alone and not firefox and IE drivers?

Comment: it would affect chrome because it blocks the startup of chromedriver.. which would not be a factor for anything but chrome

Answer (score 0):

To solve the second question , you need to use browser.window.maximize